# Trusted Platform Module (TPM) & Intel Core Chips

Tags: intel-core-i9

I'm currently evaluating a new gaming rig for home and one of my requirements is that I get a machine that allows for bitlocker to be used seamlessly.  In other words, I need to make sure I have a Trusted Platform Module so that I am not forced to enter boot passwords.

The machines I'm looking at seem to indicate that they will be utilizing the Intel Core i9 processors.  But their documentation doesn't seem to address this clearly.  Looks like Intel has branded many of their own security features and it is not my area of expertise.

Can anyone tell me if TPM is included on the i9 9900K processor so that I won't need to address that in another area?

https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/186605/intel-core-i9-9900k-processor-16m-cache-up-to-5-00-ghz.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be looking at motherboards for TPM support, not CPUs.

Some of them come with a header for a TPM device to be added to the system.

Intel chipsets that support [Intel Management Engine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_Management_Engine#Modules) come with a firmware implementation of TPM.

**Update:**

It is also worth noting that CPUs do come with TPM functions built-in these days. Some budget boards with low end chipsets still might not utilize the TPM functionality in the CPU though.

Comment: Thanks @Romen.  This is the motherboard I'm looking at and I foundd a reference to a connector.  Do you think that means it has the chipset or can be added? https://www.asus.com/us/Motherboards/ROG-MAXIMUS-XI-HERO-WI-FI/specifications/

Comment: That motherboard has a [Z390](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/133293/intel-z390-chipset.html) chipset which reports that it has IME and [Intel PTT](https://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/white-papers/enterprise-security-platform-trust-technology-white-paper.pdf). The header is useful if you mean to add an aftermarket TPM module. That may be useful if you work for an organization that requires a specific hardware TPM to log in to company resources.

Comment: Thank you.  Your help has been very much appreciated today.

Answer (score -1):

It's on the list shown on this web site:

https://mspoweruser.com/microsoft-support-windows-11-intel-amd-qualcomm-processors/

Comment: Link only answer

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1089472)